# Create String From Character Images

Tags: android, onclick

Could anybody provide me the code? I am new in android. How can I create string with alphabet images for instance I have A-Z alphabet images.

I want to create my name like "jubin" click on that alphabet image one by one.

Comment: If you can click on image 'A' then it will show a .. am i right ? do you want this type functionality ?

Comment: Yes exactly i want this type of functionality. For example if i click a it will show a if i click b it will show and so on.So that it will make string.

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to take individual imageview for all those images . Suppose you want Alphabet A-Z then you have to take 26 ImageView and set Alphabet images into individual imageview .

There is setTag Property of image view so,you have to setTag for each imageView.

### Example

If your first imageview have alphabet 'A' then you have to set Tag = 'A' , if imageview has alphabet 'B' then you have to set Tag = 'B' and so on...

So when you click on any image view you can get that tag using imageView.getTag() method.

you have to implement onClick method of imageview so you can get tag of individual imageView .

Comment: How can i set the tag when i set the tag it gives me error no resource found.Could you please tell me how can i set the tag.

Comment: I have set the tag and get the tag value but how can i set the tag value on text view .I mean to say that when i click on A image the text view show A and when i will click B the A will overwrite to B but i want string like ABC...Please Help Me.

Comment: for that you need to store all the character in one string . You have t add all the tags in string then you have to display that string to textview for that you can user string function of java .

Comment: Is there no anyother option ? actually i want to show my alphabets one by one i want it should work like keyboard.

Comment: Thanks for help i got the idea i use the getText() and implement the new character so that it will create string.